# How to create windows image in packer using the keypair

Tags: packer

I am creating the windows image with username and password using packer. It is working fine. I can able to create image.

My requirement is i need to create the windows image with **key pair** using packer. I have searched a lot but not found any document to create windows image with key pair.

Please let me know how to do this using packer.

Comment: Could you clarify. Do you mean to create an AMI with OpenSSH, or WinRM?

Comment: I am creating an windows AMI using WinRM. Please let us know how to create an AMI with Keypair

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand your exact question but I'll make a guess.

You want to build a Windows AMI which when launched sets a random Administrator password which is encrypted with the *keypair*.

This is how Packer will work if don't specify any `winrm_password`, and if you don't specify any `ssh_keypair_name` and no `ssh_private_key_file` Packer will create a temporary *keypair*.

If you want to use a existing *keypair* just define `ssh_keypair_name` and `ssh_private_key_file`.

The random *Administrator* password will be set by the instance when launching the first time and will be encrypted with the public key from the *keypair*. To get the password you need to decrypt it with the corresponding private ssh key. See [AWS CLI - get password data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/get-password-data.html) and [EC2 - Windows Passwords](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-passwords.html)

Comment: Hi Rickard, Thanks for your reply i want to create windows AMI without using winrm_password. My requirement i should not give the administrator password . I want to give an existing keypair to create AMI. Please provide me the sample code in packer for my requirment

Comment: i am using the below command to create windows image on packer.    {
    "builders": [
 {
"type": "amazon-ebs",
"region": "us-east-1",
"source_ami": "ami-abf616bd", ----> WINDOWS AMI ID
"instance_type": "m3.medium",
"ssh_keypair_name" : "test",
        "ssh_private_key_file" : "/root/packer/test.pem",
        "ami_name": "windows-ami-rdptest1",
        "access_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "secret_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     }
  ]
}

Comment: it is not creating the image. the command is stopped with the message   amazon-ebs: Waiting for SSH to become available... . Please let me know how to create windows AMI

Comment: Windows doesn't come with ssh. Either you use it the way I detailed in my answer with a random Administrator password with requires your private ssh key to decrypt or you need to install OpenSSH on it an access it that way with a ssh key. (That doesn't mean that you can log in without a password in the UI)

Comment: The example Packer template you give try to use SSH which is not installed by default on Windows AMI's. You need to switch to one that has that pre-installed or install and enable it via a user-script.